# How to customize and color a Matlab 2D-line?

Tags: matlab

I used this code to draw every 2D-line in the following picture :

**Code:**

```
plot([p1(2),p2(2)],[p1(1),p2(1)],':bs');
```

**Result:**

[image]

As you can see, every line is composed of:

- 1 right point (a blue square).
- 1 left point (a blue square).
- 1 line in between (a dashed blue line).

I want to have a different color for each component of the line.And if possible, how to modify the type too of every component .

For example I want the result to be like this for every line:

- 1 right point (a blue filled square) .
- 1 left point (a *red* filled circle).
- 1 line in between (a dashed *green* line).

How can I plot those colors?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decompose your plot procedure in three operations:

```
hold on

% First point (blue filled squares)
scatter(p1(2), p1(1), [], 'bs', 'filled')

% Second point point (red filled squares)
scatter(p2(2), p2(1), [], 'rs', 'filled')

% Dashed green line in between
plot([p1(2),p2(2)],[p1(1),p2(1)],'g--');
```

Best,